# I hv 2 tables patients(name field) and medications(completed field) I want to find patientname and medication info if medication completed == false

Tags: laravel-5

Get number of patients with incomplete medications and Patient name with medication details.

I tried this in my PatientsController index method

```php
$ontreatment = Patient::all()->medications->where('completed', false)->get();
```

My Patient.php has relationship as follows

```php
public function medications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Medication');
}
```

My Medication.php model has following relationship:

```php
public function patients()    
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');    
}
```

my route is like following:

```php
Route::get('/patients', 'PatientsController@index');
```

No. of patients who have not completed their medication and a table with patient name and medication details(Clinician,treatment,treatmentDate...) if treatment is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could constrain your `medications` relationship as follows:

```
$ontreatment = Patients::whereHas('medications', function($query) {
    $query->where('completed', false);
})->get();
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I really cant figure out why its giving a an error (un expected '}') yet the code looks syntactically right).

Comment: Missed a semi-colon there. I have added it now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: The code is Ok for now but confused..dont know where to paste it and how to access the $ontreatment variable. Am a laravel beginner.

Comment: Sorry, can't be of much help with that. This answer is within the scope of your question. You'd need to post another question specifying what you want to achieve.

Comment: If i have 5 patients and 3 have completed their medication, i want to get the number of those who have not completed their medication (2 in this case) with information about them from the two tables. (name from patients table....clinician,admissionDate....from medications table).

Comment: Yes, this query will give you that result.